# Is it necessary to manually inject into each class?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to incorporate Dagger2 into my app, but the object I'm trying to inject is always `null` unless I manually call `inject()`. I thought `inject()` is necessary only for activities/services/fragments that are created by the system. Is it actually necessary to manually inject into all classes that have dependencies?

Here's my simple example:

```
public class Foo {
  @Inject Bar bar;
  ...
}
```

I have a module to provide `Bar`:

```
@Module
public final class BarModule {

  public BarModule() {}

  @Provides
  Bar provideBar () {
    return new Bar();
  }
}
```

And then I have a central component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {BarModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
  Bar buildBar();
  void inject(Foo foo);
}
```

In my application, I build the component:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder().barModule(new BarModule()).build();
```

But, `bar` is always `null`, unless I also call `inject()`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
DaggerAppComponent.builder().barModule(new BarModule()).build().inject(foo);
```

Is it really necessary to define/call inject for every single class that has a dependency? I don't see such inject() calls everywhere in example code, so I'm thinking there's something I'm doing fundamentally wrong.

*EDIT*

Based on @DavidMedenjak's answer, I tried:

```
public class Bar {

    @Inject
    Bar() {}

    public int hello(int b) {
        return b + 5;
    }
}
```

Without a module or component, I now do:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Hello is " + bar.hello(5));
```

which returns an NPE because bar is null.

*EDIT 2*
I think the problem is that I didn't bootstrap the injection by creating the component and calling it. What I needed is:

```
AppComponent comp;
comp = DaggerAppComponent.create();
bar = comp.buildBar();
```

Which, for a one-level object, is non-sensical, but for a dependency chain, the component would create the rest of the objects in the chain.

Comment: `inject` is the "starting point" of injection. Usually you `inject` manually some high level object like activity/service and they have a number of fields which are injected and the framework recursively injects all the dependencies. So you usually don't call `inject` much since all your objects are a single tree. For an object whose constructor has no parameters there isn't much point in doing DI, BUT doing DI for it means you won't need to change the code to add dependencies later on.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought `inject()` is necessary only for activities/services/fragments that are created by the system.

Correct.

> Is it actually necessary to manually inject into all classes that have dependencies?

Nope. You should use constructor injection whenever possible.

1. Get rid of `BarModule`. Avoid calling the constructor from `@Provides` annotated method), you don't need a module to use constructor injection
2. Add `@Inject` to `Bar`'s constructor to signal Dagger how to create the object

   ```
   class Bar {
     @Inject Bar() {}
   }
   ```

That's all there is to it. Dagger now knows how to create `Bar`. Add scopes & qualifiers to the class, dependencies as constructor parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought, but it doesn't work for me. Bar is still null for me: